# Hadoop WordCount.java Dependency Issues

Tags: hadoop, dependencies, classpath, word-count

I am trying to compile WordCount.java file into jar inside of /Desktop/Hadoop/playground/src.

Here's the command I am using.

***javac -classpath hadoop-1.2.1-core.jar -d playground/classes playground/src/WordCount.java***

The compiler seem to be getting invoked, however I am getting tons of errors like  this

```
error: package org.apache.hadoop.conf does not exist import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration
```

How do I go about fixing this?

May be there is an answer to this issue already. However I could not fix it.

Comment: Is you hadoop-1.2.1-core.jar in the current directory from where you are executing javac?

Comment: @JtheRocker It is in Desktop/hadoop folder. My java file is in Desktop/hadoop/playground folder

Comment: Its really this error that I am finding really hard to circumvent. {class file for org.apache.commons.cli.Options not found}

Comment: So you are running the command from terminal after you did a `cd Desktop/hadoop`. Or in other words is your current directory Desktop/hadoop from where you are running your javac command?

Comment: I also hope you have already read the [about section of stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about), to understand how things work here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the paths of hadoop-1.2.1-core.jar and all the other dependent jars  correctly --

Try this exactly while you are in the `Desktop/hadoop` directory (valid in your case only solely based upon the inputs you provided in the comments)

```
javac -classpath *:lib/* -d playground/classes playground/src/WordCount.java
```

Comment: Yep that fixed the problem. So did this command: $ javac -cp hadoop-core-0.20.203.0.jar:lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar -d playground/classes playground/src/WordCount.java

Comment: Can this answer be accepted? If you think so. Just suggesting.

Comment: Actually what I provided is will include all the jars in Hadoop, so you will never get any jars missing exception.